# Triggering events in chrome from java

Tags: java, google-chrome

Is it possible to interact with Chrome from within a java application? Say for example fill in an input field and submit/trigger a button event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See WebDriver's [ChromeDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#chromedriver).

Example usage taken from [docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started):

```
// Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
searchBox.submit();
Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit();
```

Comment: You're most welcome. Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if you think this solves the problem :)